# Webpack proxying to a proxy

Tags: webpack, proxy, reverse-proxy, webpack-dev-server, http-proxy

I have the following scenario:
I am currently using a browser extension to access company resources via a proxy server (proxy.company.co.uk:3128) for any url that ends with company.co.uk, but I now need my webpack dev server to be able to access those resources aswell. I tried looking at the `http-proxy-middleware` repo, but only found one unaswered question on the matter and a `toProxy` flag with no explaination on how to use it.

My current proxy config is very basic:

```
devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: true,
  hot: true,
  host: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 3010,
  proxy: {
    '/api': {
      target: 'https://env-01.dev.company.co.uk/v4/',
      pathRewrite: { '^/api': '' },
      changeOrigin: true,
    },
  },
},
```

Has anyone had any success with such a setup or has ideas on how to achieve this proxying to a reverse proxy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone running into this situation in the future the approach is to setup a proxy agent and use it as the agent for the webpack dev server's http proxy, such as:

```
const HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');
*************
devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: true,
  hot: true,
  host: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 3010,
  proxy: {
    '/api': {
      agent: new HttpsProxyAgent('http://proxy.company.co.uk:3128'),
      target: 'https://env-01.dev.company.co.uk/v4/',
      pathRewrite: { '^/api': '' },
      changeOrigin: true,
    },
  },
},
```

Be careful about the proxy protocol, depending on how the reverse proxy is set up you might need to use http even if the actual endpoint you are trying to call is on https.

Comment: If I have the same agent and target URL(except the port number), I just want that only `/api` call to go to the actual server and not to the localhost, then how can I achieve this?